# Add elements to Blueprint Select component popover?

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, blueprintjs

Blueprint's [Select](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#select/select-component) component is exactly what I need for my current React project, with one exception: I need to add some elements to its popover and don't see any way to do it.

Specifically, I'd like to add a title (e.g. an H2 element) above the filter input, and a bar of buttons (e.g., some Button components in a DIV) below the list. Select seems highly configurable but I see no way to add elements inside the popover...what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jordan's suggestions above, plus a little experimentation, ultimately yielded a workable answer:

1. Set `filterable` to false to hide the built-in filter input.
2. Use `itemListRenderer` to render not only the dropdown items, but also an InputGroup to serve as a replacement filter.
3. Use InputGroup's `inputRef` prop to capture a ref to the underlying HTML input. Use that to focus the input when it appears, via the `onOpening` property of Select's `popoverProps` prop.

Here's a simple component implementing the above:

```
// Extends Blueprint's Select component with header and footer props that
// can be any arbitrary elements or components
class ExtendedSelect extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputRef = null;
    this.state = {query: ""};
  }

  handleInputChanged = event => {
    this.setState({query: event.target.value});
  }

  receiveInputRef = (ref) => {
    this.inputRef = ref;
  }

  handlePopoverOpening = () => {
    if (this.inputRef) {
      this.inputRef.focus();
    }
  }

  listRenderer = ({filteredItems, renderItem}) => {
    // Apply the supplied item renderer to the filtered list of items
    const renderedItems = filteredItems.map(renderItem);

    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.header}
        <InputGroup inputRef={this.receiveInputRef} value={this.state.query} onChange={this.handleInputChanged} leftIcon="search" />
        <Menu>
          {renderedItems}
        </Menu>
        {this.props.footer}
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Select
          items={this.props.items}
          filterable={false}
          query={this.state.query}
          itemListRenderer={this.listRenderer}
          itemPredicate={this.props.itemPredicate}
          itemRenderer={this.props.itemRenderer}
          popoverProps={{onOpening:this.handlePopoverOpening}}
          onItemSelect={this.props.onItemSelect}
          >

          {this.props.children}
        </Select>
    );
  }
}
```

(Note that I'm only passing some of Select's props into the custom component—I suspect I'd know a way to pass them all were I a more experienced React developer.)

This works surprisingly well—e.g., other than a little work to focus the input when it appears, all of Select's other built-in behavior works as expected, like keyboard navigation of the menu while the input is focused.

Comment: Great! That's exactly [what I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130239/add-elements-to-blueprint-select-component-popover#comment91313174_52161931). Also if you want to pass all the `this.props` at once, you can do it using the spread operator: `<Select filterable={false} query={this.state.query} itemListRenderer={this.listRenderer} popoverProps={{onOpening:this.handlePopoverOpening}}  {...this.props}>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extend the select's Menu and add custom elements to it, then you have to provide the `itemListRenderer` prop.

[Here's what the docs says](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#select/select-component.custom-menu):

> By default, Select renders the displayed items in a Menu. This
>   behavior can be overridden by providing the **itemListRenderer** prop,
>   giving you full control over the layout of the items. For example, you
>   can group items under a common heading, or render large data sets
>   using react-virtualized.

**itemListRenderer** example:

> If provided, the itemListRenderer prop will be called to render the contents of the dropdown menu. It has access to the items, the current query, and a renderItem callback for rendering a single item. A ref handler (itemsParentRef) is given as well; it should be attached to the parent element of the rendered menu items so that the currently selected item can be scrolled into view automatically.

Therefore in the `Menu` component's body you can place your custom headings and buttons:

```
import { ItemListRenderer } from "@blueprintjs/select";

const renderMenu: ItemListRenderer<Film> = ({ items, itemsParentRef, query, renderItem }) => {
    const renderedItems = items.map(renderItem).filter(item => item != null);
    return (
        <Menu ulRef={itemsParentRef}>
            <h2>Your heading can be styled here</h2>
            <MenuItem
                disabled={true}
                text={`Found ${renderedItems.length} items matching "${query}"`}
            />
            {renderedItems}
            <div>
              <button>Button name</button>
            </div>
        </Menu>
    );
};

<FilmSelect
    itemListRenderer={renderMenu}
    itemPredicate={filterFilm}
    itemRenderer={renderFilm}
    items={...}
    onItemSelect={...}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, `itemListRenderer` only controls the area below the search/filter input, and I want to put a header at the top of the popover _above_ the input. Ideally there's be a `popoverRenderer` or a `filterInputRenderer` or something, but I don't see anything like that.

Comment: You're welcome! Looking into the [Select source code](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/27e9aff0ef4aaf437e1dee34e14bdc12f70c6422/packages/select/src/components/select/select.tsx#L147), there's no official API way to render something before the filterable input. It's a workaround to pass `filterable=false`, that will hide the filterable input. Therefore you can render your header component at the top of the menu and later implement and render a custom filtration below the header. [This is already mentioned in the docs](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#select/select-component.querying).

Comment: Despite it's a custom filtration, it will reuse most of the Blueprint Select API. Please check [Querying](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#select/select-component.querying) and [Controlled usage](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#select/select-component.controlled-usage) documentation sections.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestions and a bit of experimentation ultimately yielded a workable answer (posted below.)

Comment: Glad I helped and supported you :)